# Two dimensional array column major order

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

This question is given in my assignment, but I am very confused about the notation of **array declaration.** Any idea what that is supposed to express?

*Given a two dimensional array A[2:3, 9:18] stored in column major order with base address 100 and size of each element is 4 bytes. Find the address of A[4,12].*

Comment: If you are confused, ask your tutor to explain rather than asking random people on the internet to answer it for you.

Comment: I strongly believe that random people on the internet are much more helpful than my tutor.

Comment: Just to clear things out, this is nothing standard form I know, the best person to ask will be the provider of this assigment.

Comment: `A[2:3, 9:18]` is not a notation that I'm familiar with. Are you sure you copied that part correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calculating addresses of 2D array elements, you need to know how they're organized.  Column-major ordering tells you that the 2D array is arranged as a list of columns.  So that means each successive element is the next one in a column, which wraps around to the next adjacent column.

If you know the dimensions of this array, the base address, and the element size, you can calculate the address of an element at a specific row and column.  Here's the formula for calculating the address of an element in a row-major ordered array.  If you can understand that, you could modify it to work for column-major arrays.

```
addr = base_addr + row * num_cols * elem_size + col * elem_size;
```